# How to deserialize a JSON object to a Java collection using Jackson in a Spring application that registered the DefaultScalaModule?

Tags: java, spring, scala, jackson, spring-rest

I am authoring a Java library that provides REST endpoints through Spring controllers. The payload of one the endpoint is an instance of my `JavaRoutine` class, for which I provide a JSON serializer/deserializer pair. Here it is (slightly simplified):

```
@JsonSerialize(using = JavaRoutine.Serializer.class)
@JsonDeserialize(using = JavaRoutine.Deserializer.class)
public class JavaRoutine {
    private final String jobId;
    private final List<Object> inputValues;
    private final List<ExpressionType> inputTypes; // ExpressionType is defined in my lib

    public JavaRoutine(String jobId) {
        this.jobId = jobId;
        this.inputValues = new ArrayList<>();
        this.inputTypes = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public String getJobId() { return jobId; }

    public void addInput(Object value) {
        inputValues.add(value);
        inputTypes.add(value == null ? null : ExpressionType.getTypeForValue(value));
    }

    public static class Serializer extends StdSerializer<JavaRoutine> {
        private static final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

        public Serializer() {
            super(JavaRoutine.class);
        }

        @Override
        public void serialize(JavaRoutine routine, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException {
            gen.writeStartObject();
            gen.writeStringField("jobId", routine.jobId);
            gen.writeArrayFieldStart("inputs");
            int inputCount = routine.inputValues.size();
            for (int i = 0; i < inputCount; i++) {
                gen.writeStartObject();
                gen.writeStringField("type", mapper.writeValueAsString(routine.inputTypes.get(i)));
                gen.writeStringField("value", mapper.writeValueAsString(routine.inputValues.get(i)));
                gen.writeEndObject();
            }
            gen.writeEndArray();
            gen.writeEndObject();
        }
    }

    public static class Deserializer extends StdDeserializer<JavaRoutine> {
        private static final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

        public Deserializer() {
            super(JavaRoutine.class);
        }

        @Override
        public JavaRoutine deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException {
            Map<String, Object> fields = p.readValueAs(new TypeReference<Map<String, Object>>() {});
            JavaRoutine routine = new JavaRoutine((String) fields.get("jobId");
            List<Map<String, String>> inputs = (List<Map<String, String>>) fields.get("inputs");
            for (Map<String, String> input: inputs) {
                ExpressionType inputType = mapper.readValue(input.get("type"), ExpressionType.class);
                Object inputValue = inputType == null ? null : mapper.readValue(input.get("value"), inputType.getJavaType());
                routine.addInput(inputValue);
            }
            return routine;
        }
    }
}
```

This works. Except when the application that links the library has registered the [Jackson module for Scala](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-scala), which it needs for its own purpose. (In short, the aim of this Jackson module is to deserialize JSON structures into Scala collections and not into Java ones.) As a consequence, the call to `p.readValueAs()` deserializes the array of "inputs" as a Scala list, which causes the cast to `List<Map<String, String>>` two lines later to fail.

What solution would you recommend?

Answer (score 1):

Have not tried you example. But running on Kubernetes with multiple Nodes in Google and got the the strange scala collections object when jumping between nodes.
This helped me half way.

Try creating mapper like below in (my guess) the Deserializer.

```
ObjectMapper mapper.registerModule(new DefaultScalaModule());
```

Also having some problems with the scala mappings. For me now the order is not kept. So Lists and Maps (LinkedHashMap) will loose the original order. :(

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, my problem is exactly the reverse: the host application has registered the Scala model in the default object mapper, and this module messes things up.